# Evitar Desplegar menu desde icono en JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas Tardes.

Como puedo evitar que se desplegué este menú cuando presione el icono de el frame?

[image: Menu a evitar]

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: No creo puedas evitarlo porque es un comportamiento del sistema operativo.

Comment: Como comenta mitsu Gami, esto no es posible, por que razón deseas que no aparezca?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas creo que es imposible, pero esto te puede servir, depende de lo que quieras hacer:

```
JFrame.setType(javax.swing.JFrame.Type.UTILITY);
```

Este comando oculta la barra superior (Incluidos el icono, el título, y los botones de maximizar y minimizar (NO el de cerrar)).

Comment: Aunque en este caso concreto no sirva (Por que el caso aquí es que se quiere mantener los botones de la derecha y quitar solamente el menu del icono (en la izquierda)), es algo útil para otros casos, pero en este realmente no.